# Why doesn't any css transtion work if elemnt is made display block from none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Consider the following scenario:

```js
$(".tab").click(function() {
  var position = $(this).index(".tabs .tab");  
  $(".content > div").removeClass("showing").removeClass("active");
  $(".content > div").eq(position).addClass("active");
  // active class makes display bock then without any delay opacity is changed by showing class
  $(".content > div").eq(position).addClass("showing");
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.content > div {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #999;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.content > .active {
 display: block;
}

.content .showing {
  opacity: 1;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab1 tab">Tab1</div>
  <div class="tab2 tab">Tab2</div>
  <div class="tab3 tab">Tab3</div>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="content1">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    content 2
  </div>
  <div class="content3">
    content 3
  </div>

</div>
```

Now when I click on any tab opacity is not transitioned. But if put a little delay between adding `active` and `showing` classes Then the tabs are transitioned well as:

```js
$(".tab").click(function() {
  var position = $(this).index(".tabs .tab");  
  $(".content > div").removeClass("showing").removeClass("active");
  $(".content > div").eq(position).addClass("active").delay(10).queue(function(){
   $(".content > div").eq(position).addClass("showing");
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.content > div {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #999;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.content > .active {
 display: block;
}

.content .showing {
  opacity: 1;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab1 tab">Tab1</div>
  <div class="tab2 tab">Tab2</div>
  <div class="tab3 tab">Tab3</div>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="content1">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    content 2
  </div>
  <div class="content3">
    content 3
  </div>

</div>
```

Now after adding a delay from the point where content is displayed block the transitions work well. My questions are:

1. Why don't transition work when opacity is changed directly with display propert? Why does transtion work when there is some delay between display block and opacity:1?
2. If I put a delay of 0 seconds even then transition works correctly. why?
3. In my second example if I quickly click tabs then the `showing` class no longer adds. why? And why does adding `dequeue` to `$(".content > div").eq(position).addClass("showing");` solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your headline question, not all CSS properties are animatable.

- `display` *is not* animatable
- `opacity` *is* animatable

---

**Further Reading:**

*[CSS Animated Properties](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)* by Mozilla Developer Network

---

For the sake of demonstration, here is an example of tabbed content fade-in and fade-out just using the CSS pseudo-class `:target` (obviating the need for any scripting in jQuery or javascript):

```css
.tabbed-content {
position: relative;
}

a[class^="tab"] {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0 15px;
color: #000;
background-color: #ccc;
border-right: 2px solid white;
text-decoration: none;
transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
}

div[id^="content"] {
position: absolute;
top: 62px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 72px;
opacity: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
}

.tab1:hover,
#content1 {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.tab2:hover,
#content2 {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
}

.tab3:hover,
#content3 {
color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

div[id^="content"]:target {
opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbed-content">
<a href="#content1" class="tab1">Tab1</a>
<a href="#content2" class="tab2">Tab2</a>
<a href="#content3" class="tab3">Tab3</a>

<div id="content1">
Content 1
</div>

<div id="content2">
Content 2
</div>

<div id="content3">
Content 3
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131569/discussion-on-answer-by-rounin-why-doesnt-any-css-transtion-work-if-elemnt-is-m).